# Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap

Tags: solr

I did a setup of sample Sitecore Instance (sc82solr), and followed the configuration from the following link

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr

Found the Solr is working fine.

When I browse the Sitecore Site (sc82solr), I am getting the error like below ?

> Could not find configuration node:
>      contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more
>      information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node:
>      contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap

Can someone suggest, what could be the issue ?

Comment: I have observed we get this error when, the required dlls (from solr support package) are not copied to the bin folder.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have some lucene leftovers in your config files.

> Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldMap

This says that something is referencing `fieldMap` node under `defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration` node.

It should not be there if you disabled all the lucene configs.

Check your `App_config` folder for `defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration` string.

It's most probably one of those files which should be disabled/removed:

- `App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config`
- `App_Config\Include\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config`
- `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Analytics.config`
- `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config`
- `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config`
- `App_Config\Include\Social\Sitecore.Social.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config`

Answer (score 2):

You still have the Lucene configuration files active. These need to be disabled.

> contentSearch/indexConfigurations/default**Lucene**IndexConfiguration/fieldMap

Depending on your exact Sitecore version, this differs a bit. Look to the section "Configure the Solr search provider" here: [Configure a search and indexing provider](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider)

Look for the Enable/Disable spreadsheet for your version, make sure all the disabled files are actually renamed or removed from your system. This can easily get messed up if you deploy your SOLR configuration files to an instance that previously had Lucene active.

> This filter enables you to see a list of all the configuration files you need to enable or disable if you are using Solr as your search and indexing provider.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it helps. I just renamed only the files mentioned in the link provided in the question, after renaming the Lucene config files, the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and identified that the configuration tag 
`defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration` in file   `Include/Feature/Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.config` had to be commented out.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places noticed Lucene config using sc82 rev. 180406
after removed the following config files resolved the issue.

```
 Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Speak.ContentSearch.Lucene.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\FXM\Sitecore.FXM.Lucene.DomainsSearch.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\Social\Sitecore.Social.Lucene.Index.Analytics.Facebook.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\Social\Sitecore.Social.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config
  Website\App_Config\Include\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.Lucene.Index.List.config
```